# How to set a symfony session

Tags: php, symfony, session

This is probably a ridiculous question, but I know Symfony now only about a few months and I've never configured a session. I understand what's going on in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html), but where to I instantiate the new Session? Do I do it inside my editAction?

Because I have an editAction and as soon as someone make an edit an email is sent to a supervisor, but how can I limit it to one email per order edit per session?

Do I just have to add something like this inside my editAction?

```
$session = new Session();
$session->start();

// set and get session attributes
$session->set('order', '...');
$session->set('supervisorEmail', '...');
$session->set('time', '...');
```

Can somebody please help me with a complete sample or guide me? I'll appreciate it really very much. Thank you.

Comment: There is session service that You can inject wherever you want.

Answer (score 4):

session is automatically started by kernel, so you dont have to start it manually. In a controller, you can retrieve via the request :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;    

public function editAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $session->set('order', '...');
    $session->set('supervisorEmail', '...');
    $session->set('time', '...');
}
```

You can also check if a session already has a property, like this :

```
if (false === $session->has('order') {
    $session->set('order', '...');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Setting a session variable already start to make sense, now how do I check if an email is already sent to prevent more if the same obect is edited again in the same session?

Comment: when sending the email for the first time, register a session variable. and upon edition, check if this variable is registered or not with `$session->has()` before sending a new email.